# Use of computeDistanceBetween gives error : '"cannot resolve 'google'"

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to write an app and one of the things it is supposed to do is calculate the distance between the current location and a number of other markers(which are given by a kml file).

[image: here is my code]

I have imported google play services(maps & location only tho), could the problem be a missing library? I haven't found anything saying that geometry library need to be imported anywhere besides the activity it is used in... Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: `google.maps.geometry.spherical` is **Javascript** code. Not part of the Android API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/reference

Comment: yes, so no importing needed right? so why would it give that error?

Comment: It gives that error because it doesn't exist. Javascript != Java. Here's the method your code shows, but that is not the Android API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should do something like this to compute the distance.
Call the static method `Location.distanceBetween()`, and the distance will be populated in the first element of the `distance` float array.

```
float[] distance = new float[2];

Location.distanceBetween( from.latitude, from.longitude,
        latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, distance);

if( distance[0] < 5 ){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: does this method returns road distance?

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick No, this method does not return distance based on roads.  For getting distance based on road directions, use the distance matrix api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

You can use DistanceTo method to calculate the distance between the two Locations

**for example:**

```
    Location m1 = new Location("1");
    Location m2 = new Location("2");
    float distance;
    m1.setLongitude(<your longitude>);
    m1.setLatitude(<your latitude>);
    m2.setLatitude(<marker's latitude>);
    m2.setLongitude(<marker's longitude>);
    distance = m1.distanceTo(m2);
    disntaceBetween.setText("Distance is: " + distance + "m");
```